# Best way to periodically run power-shell script on Azure Virtual Machine from other VM inside subscription

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-node-sdk

Trying to use Azure nodejs SDK and tested virtual machine run command as mentioned in [Get StdOut from RunCommand using Azure VM Javascript SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54152364/get-stdout-from-runcommand-using-azure-vm-javascript-sdk?answertab=active#tab-top).
Performance of this call is poor. Does user have permissions to change the timeout value for the Virtual Machine run-command?

Any other alternative to send the script.

Comment: are the vm's on the same vnet? and do the machines allow for remote powershell:  Enable-PSRemoting -Force

Comment: Not in the same vnet but in same subscription.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,the performance of "run command" way is not so good,if you get timeout errors using SDK, maybe calling rest APIs directly will be a workaround.

In terms of underlying , while you use SDK to call run command function , it calls this API :

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<your subscription ID>/resourceGroups/<resource group name>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/<VM Name>/runCommand?api-version=2018-04-01

Request Headers:
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <access token>

Request Body:
{"commandId":"RunPowerShellScript","script":["<script content>"]}
```

Once you called it successfully , you will get a 202 response code and in response header , there will be a param "location" whose value is a link and you can get your command running status using it : 
[image]

[image]

With this way , you can monitor running status by calling this url instead of waiting for the response for a long time .

Besides "run command" way to run ps script on Azure VMs, there are 3 other ways to do it:

1. Azure VM custom script extension
2. Remote PowerShell
3. Azure Automation DSC

[This blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_stranger/2017/07/31/using-azure-custom-script-extension-to-execute-scripts-on-azure-vms/) described them well, you can choose one of them based on your requirement.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi ，how's going there ?

Comment: Main thing here is one VM is triggering script to all other VM's in Azure Subscription. I guess all the options need some extra configuration and my goal to minimize them.

Comment: To be specific I have a nodejs app in VM  trying to send powershell script to all the VMs in Azure subscription. I tested out the user identity approach provided by Azure where VM assumes the identity and makes the run command call but it is slow. So, currently I am looking into strategy provided in this article - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8558bc2a-987b-4898-b5b5-059d64842001/virtual-machine-administrator-login?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows. Have a common AD user on all VMs and run node application with that user and make remote calls.